# Apache, SSL Client certificate, LDAP authorizations

Tags: apache, ssl, ldap

I posted this question on serverfault.com, but I had no answer, so I'm trying here...
Is it possible to mix mod_ssl and mod_auth_ldap so that the authentication is done with the client certificate and authorizations with mod_auth_ldap (Require ldap-group)? If so, can you give me some pointer? Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is off-topic here and is duplicated in https://serverfault.com/questions/314362/apache-ssl-client-certificate-ldap-authorizations/1034538.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, for those interested, apache requires the presence of an AuthType directive and the validation of the username by some module.

So I have written a very short module that accepts AuthType Any and accepts any username.

The configuration looks like that:

```
<Location /slaptest>
    Allow from all
    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLVerifyDepth 1

    SSLUserName SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN

    AuthType Any
    AuthAnyAuthoritative on

    AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://vldap-rectech/ou=XXX,ou=YYY,o=ZZZ?cn"
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
    AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=UUU,ou=Users,ou=XXX,ou=YYY,o=ZZZ"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword "******"
    AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN on
    AuthLDAPGroupAttribute member
    AuthLDAPRemoteUserIsDN off
    Require valid-user
    Require ldap-group cn=ADMIN,ou=Groups,ou=XXX,ou=YYY,o=ZZZ
</Location>
```

UPDATE:

The code of the module is listed below. It defines the following directives:

AuthAnyAuthoritative on/off

AuthAnyCheckBasic on/off

If AuthAnyCheckBasic is on, the module will check that the username obtained from the certificate matches the on in the Authorization header.

```
#include "apr_strings.h"
#include "apr_md5.h"            /* for apr_password_validate */
#include "apr_lib.h"            /* for apr_isspace */
#include "apr_base64.h"         /* for apr_base64_decode et al */
#define APR_WANT_STRFUNC        /* for strcasecmp */
#include "apr_want.h"

#include "ap_config.h"
#include "httpd.h"
#include "http_config.h"
#include "http_core.h"
#include "http_log.h"
#include "http_protocol.h"
#include "http_request.h"
#include "ap_provider.h"

#include "mod_auth.h"

typedef struct {
    int authoritative;
    int checkBasic;
} auth_any_config_rec;

static void *create_auth_any_dir_config(apr_pool_t *p, char *d)
{
    auth_any_config_rec *conf = apr_pcalloc(p, sizeof(*conf));

    /* Any failures are fatal. */
    conf->authoritative = 1;
    conf->checkBasic = 0;

    return conf;
}

static const command_rec auth_any_cmds[] =
{
    AP_INIT_FLAG("AuthAnyAuthoritative", ap_set_flag_slot,
                 (void *)APR_OFFSETOF(auth_any_config_rec, authoritative),
                 OR_AUTHCFG,
                 "Set to 'Off' to allow access control to be passed along to "
                 "lower modules if the UserID is not known to this module"),
    AP_INIT_FLAG("AuthAnyCheckBasic", ap_set_flag_slot,
                 (void *)APR_OFFSETOF(auth_any_config_rec, checkBasic),
                 OR_AUTHCFG,
                 "Set to 'On' to compare the username with the one in the "
                 "Authorization header"),
    {NULL}
};

module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA auth_any_module;

static void note_basic_auth_failure(request_rec *r)
{
    apr_table_setn(r->err_headers_out,
                   (PROXYREQ_PROXY == r->proxyreq) ? "Proxy-Authenticate"
                                                   : "WWW-Authenticate",
                   apr_pstrcat(r->pool, "Basic realm=\"", ap_auth_name(r),
                               "\"", NULL));
}

/* Determine user ID, and check if it really is that user, for HTTP
 * basic authentication...
 */
static int authenticate_any_user(request_rec *r)
{
    auth_any_config_rec *conf = ap_get_module_config(r->per_dir_config,
                                                       &auth_any_module);

    /* Are we configured to be Basic auth? */
    const char *current_auth = ap_auth_type(r);
    if (!current_auth || strcasecmp(current_auth, "Any")) {
        return DECLINED;
    }

    if (!r->user) {
        return conf->authoritative ? HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED : DECLINED;
    }

    if (conf->checkBasic) {
        /* Get the appropriate header */
        const char *auth_line = apr_table_get(r->headers_in,
                (PROXYREQ_PROXY == r->proxyreq)
                        ? "Proxy-Authorization"
                        : "Authorization");

        if (!auth_line) {
            note_basic_auth_failure(r);
            return HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED;
        }

        if (strcasecmp(ap_getword(r->pool, &auth_line, ' '), "Basic")) {
            /* Client tried to authenticate using wrong auth scheme */
            ap_log_rerror(APLOG_MARK, APLOG_ERR, 0, r,
                          "client used wrong authentication scheme: %s", r->uri);
            note_basic_auth_failure(r);
            return HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED;
        }

        /* Skip leading spaces. */
        while (apr_isspace(*auth_line)) {
            auth_line++;
        }

        char *decoded_line = apr_palloc(r->pool, apr_base64_decode_len(auth_line) + 1);
        int length = apr_base64_decode(decoded_line, auth_line);
        /* Null-terminate the string. */
        decoded_line[length] = '\0';

        const char *user = ap_getword_nulls(r->pool, (const char**)&decoded_line, ':');

        if (strcasecmp(user, r->user)) {
            return HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED;
        }
    }

    r->ap_auth_type = "Any";
    ap_log_error(APLOG_MARK, APLOG_DEBUG, 0, r->server,
            "Accepting user: %s", r->user);

    return OK;
}

static void register_hooks(apr_pool_t *p)
{
    ap_hook_check_user_id(authenticate_any_user,NULL,NULL,APR_HOOK_MIDDLE);
}

module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA auth_any_module =
{
    STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF,
    create_auth_any_dir_config,    /* dir config creater */
    NULL,                          /* dir merger --- default is to override */
    NULL,                          /* server config */
    NULL,                          /* merge server config */
    auth_any_cmds,                 /* command apr_table_t */
    register_hooks                 /* register hooks */
};
```