# 2 way ssl tomcat stateless service scale

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, horizontal-scaling

I have a stateless service in java, deployed in a tomcat web server and I also have configured the 2 way ssl autentication. Up to this point everything works fine. When a I have a new client, I only have to put a new client certificate into my trustore and restart my service and the new client can use my service.

But I need to horizontal scaling, as my service is stateless, no problem with that, but if I have 10 servers I don't want to go to each one and make this change in each trustore file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

An usual approach is to use a load-balancer like apache behind the tomcat cluster and let it take care of SSL, this way you can horizontally scale as much as you like without worrying about key stores and certificates. Here are the docs for [apache ssl](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html) config, and [how to set it as a load balancer](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html).

Comment: I'm using haproxy, a layer 3 high availability balancer, because Apache only gives me the posibility to authenticate, so in app layer I need client certificate in order to check the authorization to use the services. If I use apache I think client certificate doesn't  travel to web servers where I'm doing load balance

Comment: Ok, that's an interesting approach, TLS is meant to be used as a protocol for authentication, the authorization mechanism is actually an extension to it, I'd think about it twice though, are you sure that TLS gives you enough flexibility to manage all your authorization needs? I'd rather combine it with some other authorization framework, and apache can handle that too, here's an example with LDAP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635380/apache-ssl-client-certificate-ldap-authorizations

Comment: You should be able to configure your load balancer to terminate the SSL connection but still deliver you the certificates. So the truststore is only required at the load balancer.

Comment: That is a posibility, but as I'm using haproxy and I have everything resolved by Tomcat, I was wondering if I can do something else with tomcat and files and put this things in cluster, configuring apache to send me back the client certificate is something that we can do, but I have to open port 80 and wait for client certificate in the request, that is not a standard solution.