# Apache configuration - client cert for authentication, ldap for authorization

Tags: apache, authentication, ssl

I'm trying to configure Apache to do the following:
- authenticate users with a client X509 certificate
- look up the user (based on their CN, or other attribute in their certificate) in an LDAP directory
- allow users access if they are a member of an LDAP group and deny them if they're not

Seems like something straight-forward but the only discussions I can find on doing this are using 8-year-old plugins that for the most part don't exist any more.

I can get the certificate authentication working easily, and can get mod_authnz_ldap working as long as I prompt for a userid and password, but can't find anything that provides guidance on using client certs along with LDAP authorization. Is there a way to make this work using standard Apache modules?

Comment: Perhaps this is a known bug? https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48780

Comment: Saw that. Figured that in the intervening 5 years surely someone would have moved this problem forward. Also was able to get it to work using this 4-year-old solution [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635380/apache-ssl-client-certificate-ldap-authorizations]. But it uses the old Auth API that's gone in 2.4. Just hoping I don't have to go as far as deploying an Access Management portal product to do this for me with its agents.